# Navigation Between UIViewControllers Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have 3 ViewControllers and want to navigate between then without appearing the second one.

what actually i want to do something like this:

**FirstController**

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let secondController = SecondController();
    secondController.showThird();
```

}

**SecondController**

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
```

}
func showThird() {

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thirdId")
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)


}
```

**ThirdController**

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Comment: Why you are writing your code in didReceiveMemoryWarning() ?

Comment: oh sorry i will update it

Answer (score 0):

**appdelegate.swift**

You can push the second Viewcontroller without animation and next line you need to push Third Viewcontroller

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

 let controllerOne = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("oneId")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controllerOne, animated: false)           

let controllerTwo = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondId")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controllerTwo, animated: false)

let controllerThree = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thirdId")
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controllerThree, animated: true)

}
```

Hopefully It works for you.

Comment: but in that case user will not see the second view reight

Comment: Yes @J.Deo Do you want to show second viewController for while?

Comment: and where to call my function where i should call the third one there as i will do lots of processing there

Comment: you should write code on first screen (Next button click) Do you have any button event which gonna change the screen?

Comment: i don't want to make that based on user action

Comment: appdelagte.swift -> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions -> write code

Comment: sorry i'm beginner in swift and i don't understand what is this